# I need the domain information to display on my Reactjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am having problems with the api rendering, the api works but the information doesnt display on the table so I cant see if the show entries functionality works or the part where the user can flick throught the different pages of information. Please help.

This is the my App.js code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../src/styles.css';

function WhoisSearch() {
  const [domainName, setDomainName] = useState('');
  const [whoisData, setWhoisData] = useState(null);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(10);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://otx.alienvault.com/otxapi/indicator/domain/whois/${domainName}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setWhoisData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleShowChange = (e) => {
    setShow(parseInt(e.target.value));
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const filteredData = whoisData
    ? Object.entries(whoisData).filter(([key, value]) =>
        key.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    : [];

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredData.length / show);

  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  const paginationData = filteredData.slice(
    (currentPage - 1) * show,
    currentPage * show
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Enter a domain name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={domainName}
            onChange={(e) => setDomainName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="show">Show</label>
        <select name="show" id="show" value={show} onChange={handleShowChange}>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
        <span>entries</span>
      </div>
      <div className='form'>
        <input type="text" className='search' placeholder="Search" value={search} onChange={handleSearchChange} />
      </div>
      {whoisData && (
        <>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Record</th>
                <th>Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {paginationData.map(([key,{ name, value}]) => (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{key}</td>
                  <td>{value?.name || value}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="pagination">
            <button
              disabled={currentPage === 1}
              onClick={() => handlePageChange(currentPage - 1)}
            >
              Previous
            </button>
            {[...Array(totalPages)].map((_, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                onClick={() => handlePageChange(index + 1)}
                className={currentPage === index + 1 ? 'active' : ''}
              >
                {index + 1}
              </button>
            ))}
            <button
              disabled={currentPage === totalPages}
              onClick={() => handlePageChange(currentPage + 1)}>
              Next
              </button>
              </div>
              </>
              )}
              </div>
              );
              }
              
              export default WhoisSearch;
```

[that is what i receive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEWm9.png)

Im not sure where to go from here really. Ive tried checking if the api works, Ive tried changing parameteres in the paginationData.map. please help me.

Comment: If you console log paginationData, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it says paginationData not defined.

Comment: So how do you expect it to work while you are doing map on that variable. You need to debug why this variable is not getting set.